# USB device enumeration changes while in operation

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux

I am using a USB device with Raspberry Pi 4 which is initially enumerated as *(USB0, USB1, USB2, USB3)*. Due to some power fluctuation, all the USB ports get disconnected and reconnected again. But this time, instead of *(USB0, USB1, USB2, USB3)*, the ports get connected as *(USB0, USB3, USB4, USB5)*, which causes serial read issues in my application. My python program is using USB1 and USB2.

How can I force the devices to get reconnected with the same enumerations as before?

USB device disconnection (from dmesg log):

```
[72459.273350] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[72459.273967] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[72459.274044] option 1-1.2:1.0: device disconnected
[72459.275380] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[72459.275425] option 1-1.2:1.1: device disconnected
[72459.276084] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
[72459.276127] option 1-1.2:1.2: device disconnected
[72459.276562] option1 ttyUSB3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
[72459.276624] option 1-1.2:1.3: device disconnected
```

USB device reconnection (from dmesg log):

```
[72459.772212] option 1-1.2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[72459.772482] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[72459.772674] option 1-1.2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[72459.773101] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[72459.773305] option 1-1.2:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[72459.775595] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB4
[72459.775884] option 1-1.2:1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[72459.777303] usb 1-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB5
```

Comment: I would fix the original problem instead. Make sure there's enough power to keep the devices online until you really disconnect them.

Comment: @PMF Yes, I am trying that as well. I was curious if there is any solution to the question I asked about keeping the enumerations same.

Comment: ASFAIK no, the raspberry pi unfortunately quite randomly re-assigns ports when the devices are re-attached. This even seems to happen if you perform a reboot. That means that in either case you'll need a way to determine which device is which (in case it matters).